# How to compare corresponding elements in list/array/dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, comparison

Suppose you have two lists (or any type of grouping, it doesn't matter which one) containing variables that represent milk, eggs, and flour. For instance:

have(milk, eggs, flour)

and

need(milk, eggs, flour)

How might you go about determining whether each element >=, ==, or <= its counterpart in the other list so that you can return some indication as to whether there is or is not enough of each ingredient to make a proverbial cake or if there is enough to make more than one?

I'd really prefer not to write War and Peace for the sake of 3 comparisons. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Assuming, `milk`, `eggs`, `flour` are `class objects`, typically there should be an attribute specifying quantity (`milk.quantity` and `eggs.quantity`). Since these values would be numerical, you can use arithmetic operators.

Comment: Please provide more insights about your query with a sample example (if feasible)

Comment: The point of the variable is to store the quantity: eggs = 2 means there are 2 eggs and milk = 3 means there are 3 cups milk. So if I need 2 eggs, 1 milk, and 1 flour, but I have 4 eggs, 5 milk, and 3 flour i want it to return that 2 cakes can be made.

Comment: It's a pretty vague question because you don't specify data layouts or methods, so it's hard to get a specific answer in code. That said, you can loop over indexes or labels to compare each pair however you need to and store the results in another "grouping," no Tolstoy needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asssuming input as the following

```
milk=200
eggs=10
flour=1000

milk_reqd=100
eggs_reqd=5
flour_reqd=2000

have=[milk, eggs, flour]
need=[milk_reqd, eggs_reqd, flour_reqd]
```

**Solution**

```
import numpy as np
have=np.array(have)
need=np.array(need)
```

Now you can perform all operations like

```
need>have
```

Or

```
need<=have
```

Or

```
need-have
```

To get the number of cakes that can be made

```
n_cakes=int(min(have/need))
```

Comment: Thank you, Anant. I have been stuck on this for way too long and hadn't even considered using NumPy (I'm still very new at this), you're a life saver.

Answer (score 2):

You could use dictionaries. For instance:

```
have = {"milk": 2, "eggs": 3, "flour": 0.5}
need = {"milk": 1, "eggs": 5, "flour": 2.5}
ingredients = {i:"Yes" if have[i] >= need[i] else "No" for i in have.keys()}
```

Output:

```
print(ingredients)
{'milk': 'Yes', 'eggs': 'No', 'flour': 'No'}
```

If you want a function that tells you how many cakes you can do with the ingredients you have, you can use the following:

```
def how_many(need, have):
    results = {i:have[i]//need[i] for i in have.keys()}
    return min(results.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

If the a list of quantities that you need to compare, you can use a one-liner list comprehension (can only compare ==, > , < else it they will be overlapping operations if you use >= and <= and ==) -

```
milk_have = 10
eggs_have = 20
flour_have = 30

milk_need = 10
eggs_need = 25
flour_need = 3

have = [milk_have, eggs_have, flour_have]
need = [milk_need, eggs_need, flour_need]

['==' if i[0]==i[1] else '>' if i[0]>i[1] else '<' for i in zip(have, need)]
```

```
['==', '<', '>']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
have = ('milk', 'eggs', 'flour',"k")
need = ('milk', 'eggs', 'flour',"l")
incredients = {}
for i in range(len(have)):
   count = 0 
   if have[i] == need[i]:
      count +=1
   incredients[have[i]] = count
```

output: `{'eggs': 1, 'flour': 1, 'k': 0, 'milk': 1}`